# SAS - how to not import empty file

Tags: sas

I am trying to import all the CSV files in one folder and schedule the program in the SAS management console. Since it has empty CSV files in the folders, it failed to run the code automatically due to the errors. I was wondering if I can skip the steps of importing the empty file in the following codes.

```
`%macro drive(dir,ext); 
%local cnt filrf rc did memcnt name;

%let cnt=0;
%let filrf=mydir;
%let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));
%let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));
%if &did ne 0 %then %do;
%let memcnt=%sysfunc(dnum(&did));
%do i=0 %to &memcnt;
%let name=%qscan(%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i)),-1,.);
%if %qupcase(%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i))) ne %qupcase(&name) %then %do;
%if %superq(ext) = %superq(name) %then %do;
%let cnt=%eval(&cnt+1);
%put %qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));
        
proc import datafile="&dir\%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i))" out=dsn&cnt 
dbms=csv replace;
guessingrows=max;
run;
data dsnnew&cnt (drop=old);set dsn&cnt (rename=(party_id = old)); party_id= input(old,12.);run;
%end;
%end;
%end;
%end;
%else %put &dir cannot be opened.;
%end;
%let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
%mend drive;`
```

Comment: Do you know how to tell if the file is empty?  Also by empty do you mean 0 bytes?  Or do you mean there is only a header row but no observations.  Also do you expect all of the files to have the same columns (variables) in the same order?  If so then skip the IMPORT and just READ the files.

Comment: For the empty file, it is 0KB and no headers in it. I just want to import all the csv files and union all. How to just read the files?

Comment: CSV files have nothing to do with EXCEL so I removed that extra tag.  CSV files are just text files.

Comment: I think I need to add another if statement to determine if the file is empty or not. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

PROC IMPORT cannot handle CSV files with fewer then 2 lines.  You could just count how many lines the file has. No need to count beyond 2.

```
data _null_;
  if eof then call symputx('nobs',_n_-1);
  infile "&dir\%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i))" obs=2 end=eof;
  input;
run;
```

You can then test the value of the NOBS macro variable to decide whether or not to run PROC IMPORT>

```
%if &nobs>1 %then %do;
  ....
%end;
```

If the files all have the same structure then there is no need for the complicated macro code.  Instead just read them all with one data step.  You will have to write the code, but you will then have full control over how the variables are defined.  You could include the actual name of the file as part of the dataset.  Or perhaps extract some identifying information from the filename.

```
data want;
  length fname filename $256 ;
  infile "&dir/*.csv" filename=fname truncover dsd ;
  input @;
* skip the header lines ;
  if fname ne lag(fname) then delete;
* save the filename to a permanent variable;
  filename=fname;
* Here is where you put the code to actually read the lines ;
  input var1 var2 .... ;
run;
```